# Using results from amazon product advertising

Tags: api, product, ads, amazon-advertising-api

I am using results from one of my site on another site and clicks from that site also going to amazon using product advertising api

***Do clicks from that site also count or not? is it legal?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicks should count as long as you are using the referral tag. Because the API in question doesn't take the refferer site domain as passing parameter. so, it tracks through the customer referral tag.

Comment: thank you so much for answering nirjhar this surely removed my confusion

Comment: Feeling shy to say this. But if the answer helped, you may choose to upvote the answer and accept it.